# number_format in between strings

Tags: php, number-formatting

I am new to php and I have this code that will supposedly display floating numbers with comma.
I have the following part of my code.

```
<?php echo "          
            <table>
                     <tr>
                     <td>Bracket</td>
                     <td>Detailed Computation</td>
                     <td>Total</td>
                     </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>41- Up</td>
                     <td>Commodity Charge: {$cc_fortyone_above} x {$diff_fortyone_above} cu. m.</td>
                     <td>{$total_fortyone_above}</td>
                </tr> 
     </table>";
  ?>
```

Comment: What is your question? What isn't working?

Comment: I want to add the number_format in those variables such as {$cc_fortyone_above}

Comment: What holds you back from using `echo "[...] Commodity Charge: " . number_format($cc_fortyone_above) . " x  {$diff_fortyone_above} cu. m. [...]"`

Comment: Or even `$cc_fortyone_above = number_format($cc_fortyone_above); echo [...]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo "          
        <table>
                 <tr>
                 <td>Bracket</td>
                 <td>Detailed Computation</td>
                 <td>Total</td>
                 </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>41- Up</td>
                 <td>Commodity Charge: ".number_format($cc_fortyone_above)." x ".number_format($diff_fortyone_above)." cu. m.</td>
                 <td>{$total_fortyone_above}</td>
            </tr> 
 </table>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define variables :

```
<?php
    $cc_fortyone_above    = number_format($cc_fortyone_above);
    $diff_fortyone_above  = number_format($diff_fortyone_above);
    $total_fortyone_above = number_format($total_fortyone_above);
    echo "          
        <table>
                 <tr>
                 <td>Bracket</td>
                 <td>Detailed Computation</td>
                 <td>Total</td>
                 </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>41- Up</td>
                 <td>Commodity Charge: {$cc_fortyone_above} x {$diff_fortyone_above} cu. m.</td>
                 <td>{$total_fortyone_above}</td>
            </tr> 
        </table>";
?>
```